What is the easiest way for an American to escape from the United States
The likely political consequences in November will mean that lgbt people are no longer safe, and I am trying to get out of here as quickly as possible. I have a bachelor's degree. What's my best option for ensuring that I can leave this country?

A valid passport and a healthy bank balance?

Leaving is less of a problem, finding a place to go to (and be welcome there) is more difficult.
Generally immigration is easiest though family connections or employment. Marry a foreigner or find an employer willing to sponsor a visa for you.
Same as immigration into the US, really.

Leaving the US is not going to be much of a problem. Many countries are accepting US visitors without a visa.
The problem will be finding a place where you want to live, where you are allowed to stay longer and work, and where you are able to find a job and housing. Going from the US to western Europe, for instance, will be quite a culture change. But then you are looking for a change in culture, right?

Do you speak any language other than English? In most EU states one can get by with English, at least in urban areas, but an immigrant would be expected to learn the local language.
What kind of bachelor do you have, and what kind of job experience? Many EU states are looking for skilled immigrants, but one quick-and-easy definition of 'skilled' is an above-average salary. There are some fields where a bachelor would not get you above average.
Many parts of Europe have a housing crunch right now, so even if you find a job you might have a hard time finding a home within reasonable commute.

This answer centers on Europe because I know the conditions here. Canada might be another option for you, or other parts of the world.
